# How to give the state value to image source attribute in React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
 export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
      this.state = {
      first_name:'',
      avatar: ''
   }
 }
```

componentDidMount(){

```
axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/users/2')
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({first_name : response.data.data.first_name}),
    this.setState({avatar : response.data.data.avatar})

    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
   }


 render() {
   return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text> {this.state.first_name}</Text>
       <Text>Hello</Text>
       <Image source={this.state.avatar} />
     </View>
    );
   }
 }
```

How to give the state value to image source attribute in React native
I have the dynamic url's in {this.state.avatar} I want to give that url to source attribute.. can you please give me the correct way to pass my state value to image tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From react-native documentation :

```
source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png'}}
```

change the link with your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the image tag as follows if the image source is an URI :

```
<Image
  source={{uri: this.state.avatar}}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending of what `value` you put at the `avatar state`,

if the `value` of `avatar` is `{uri: 'http://yourlink.com'}` so you just need to use:

> source={this.state.avatar}

but if your `value` of `avatar` is just a link without `uri` so you must doing something like

> source={{uri: this.state.avatar}}